# Reading time from GPS device

Tags: c#, gps, serial-port

I'm trying to read the time from GPS messages, this is the code:

```
public void SerialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        string data = gpsPort.ReadExisting();
        string[] strArr = data.Split('$');
        for (int i = 0; i < strArr.Length; i++)
        {
            string strTemp = strArr[i];
            string[] lineArr = strTemp.Split(',');
            if (lineArr[0].Equals("GPGGA"))
            {
                try
                {
                    this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate ()
                    {
                        string time = lineArr[1].Remove(6);
                        time = time.Insert(2, ":");
                        time = time.Insert(5, ":");
                        labelGPSTime.Text = time;
                    }));
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    string err = ex.Message;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My code manages to read the time when I just start the program, but not after.
If I use a breakpoint and walk through it step by step it works, but not when it runs normally.
I tried using the same code with a timer instead of SerialPort_DataReceived, but it cuts the messages in the middle.

Comment: The DataReceived event can occur at any point after data starts to be received - so you need to buffer the data until the entire message has been received & then process it - does the message have a specific final character or a fixed length that you can wait for?. Stepping through with the debugger give time for the entire message to be received.

Comment: Possibly use the DataReceived event to fill a buffer & use a separate thread to process the incoming data - discarding anything up to $GPGGA & then waiting for cr/lf which are the checksum according to the [information I found on the format](http://www.gpsinformation.org/dale/nmea.htm#GGA). Or use the [SerialPort.ReadLine method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.readline(v=vs.110).aspx).